# set top of field based on another field in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

Can some one help me to ?
I want to move one or more field vertically based on another field that set to can grow in crystal report

for example I have a field named "Description" it is nvarchar max and it set can grow 
I want to change vertical position of another field base on description field to center of it 
you know the crystal report has no vertical alignment setting such as horizontal alignment

thanks 
farzad

Comment: Please Helpppppppppppppppppppppppppp some one

Comment: I think it is possible by changing the Top of fields base on Description field but how ???

Answer (score 0):

I think vertical allignment is not possible in crystal report but one way around is place the field where you want (When you field 1 is applied can grow) and supress it, When field1 is description field size increases then make that field visible.

Comment: I totally didn't understand your mean please make an example

Comment: what I mean is since you want to move your field vertically somewhere in design when description is increased in size so I am suggesting to create a field in target location and supress and when your description is increased then unsupress the field.. It is just an  idea and I have not tested it

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but I think an idea is change all field top , dynamically changed with height/2 of description field but I don't know how can I do this ........... I did this before in ms access vba but in c# I don't know how

Comment: In ma access report vba , i wrote this code 

Private Sub VerticallyCenter(ctl As Control)
 Dim lngHeight As Long
 lngHeight = fTextHeight(Me.ItemDesc)
 ctl.TopMargin = lngHeight / 2
End Sub

and in report Detail_Format  
i use such as this 
VerticallyCenter Me.field1
    VerticallyCenter Me.field2
    VerticallyCenter Me.field3
    VerticallyCenter Me.field4

it work greate but in C# i don't know how

Comment: ohhh you are accessing CR from C#... I don't have expertize in that I work on CR as a standalone application... I am sorry I can't help you in this aspect